# Place tikz spiral at any coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a 3d tikz picture that includes a scope canvas for placing drawings on a 2d plane inside. What I'd like to do, is place a small spiral at arbitrary xz coordinates on that canvas. I can produce a spiral, but only at the origin. Perhaps I don't understand the parametric equation, but how can I place more spirals at any x,z position?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=8,thick]
 \draw (0,-.389/2,0) -- (0,.389/2,0) -- (0,.389/2,.1952) --
    (0,-.389/2,.1952) -- cycle;

\begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
      \draw [domain=0:15,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75]
        plot ({\t r}: {0.00012*\t*\t});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: shifted spirals]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{60}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=8,thick]
    \draw (0,-.389/2,0) -- (0,.389/2,0) -- (0,.389/2,.1952) -- (0,-.389/2,.1952) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
      \foreach \i/\j in {0/black,1.5/red,3/blue,4.5/green}
        \draw [domain=0:15,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75, yshift=\i, \j]  plot ({\t r}: {0.00012*\t*\t});
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @James Oh, good - I wasn't quite sure what you wanted. You can change the position in the other direction using `xshift`, of course. But the spirals no longer look as if they are tacked to the board!

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to shift pictures in Cartesian coordinates than in polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand{\spiral}[2]{%
  \draw [domain=0:15,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75]
  plot ({#1 + 0.00012*\t*\t * cos(\t r)}, {#2 + 0.00012*\t*\t * sin(\t r)})}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=8,thick]
  \draw (0,-.389/2,0) -- (0,.389/2,0) -- (0,.389/2,.1952) --  (0,-.389/2,.1952) -- cycle;

  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
    \spiral00;
    \spiral{0}{0.1};
    \spiral{0.1}{0.2};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]